# create rook-ceph cluster on minikube

Tags: ceph

I am on **ubuntu 20.04** and trying to create a ***rook-ceph cluster***.

I have ***kvm2*** installed to try it.

This is what I am doing but I don't see the node accessing storage.

minikube start --vm-driver=kvm2
minikube mount /dev/vda1 /data/ceph

and I followed the rook installation.
Is there anything I am missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Volume using qemu and attach disk with virsh.

Like this:

```
sudo -S qemu-img create -f raw /var/lib/libvirt/images/minikube-box2-vm-disk1-50G 50G
virsh -c qemu:///system attach-disk minikube --source /var/lib/libvirt/images/minikube-box2-vm-disk1-50G --target vdb --cache none
virsh -c qemu:///system reboot --domain minikube
```